# Trouble using timeGetTime() in Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, time

Alright I'm pretty new to using VS. I'm trying to figure out the time elapsed between updates in an OpenGl program (in C), and I was planning on using timeGetTime().

I have

```
#include <windows.h>
```

at the top of my program. As well under "Project>Properties>Linker>Input", I have "Additional Dependencies" include "winmm.lib". Now whenever I try to use timeGetTime(), it gives me two errors:

```
Error   63  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _timeGetTime referenced in function _main ***.obj
```

and

```
Error   64  fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\***
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` or `MMNOTIMER` macros defined, or the prototype for `timeGetTime()` won't be included in `mmsystem.h` .

Another possibility is that you have some other declaration for `timeGetTime()` in one of your headers (or the .c source file) that's being picked up for some reason instead of the declaration in `mmsystem.h`.

The symbol that should be looked for by the linker is:

```
__imp__timeGetTime@0 (or __imp_timeGetTime on x64)
```

not

```
_timeGetTime
```

Comment: These are my other header files I've included: 
#include <gl/freeglut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

I don't know if any of them declare timeGetTime (besides windows.h when it includes mmsystem.h). I have no idea how to use macros, how could I check if WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN is defined?

Comment: @Jeff: you'd either have a `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` in your source file (or a header), or you'd have it in the project settings' "Preprocesor definitions" item.  You can try putting an `#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` just before your `#include <windows.h>` to see if that's the culprit or not.  You might also try putting `windows.h` before the other includes but that shouldn't usually be a requirement (except for the oddball case of `winsock2.h`, which to avoid conflicts has to be included before `windows.h` if you're using it).

Comment: I just had a look at `freeglut.h` - it results in `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` being defined (at least the version I looked at). You'll need to include `windows.h` before that header.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, it works now! I should've had a look through freeglut myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do timings, I'd recommend using [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of timeGetTime.  These work by using the high performance counters in Windows, which will give you much better accuracy for timings.